# Loading a set of css variables in Sveltekit from a file

Tags: css, svelte, sveltekit, tauri

I'm building an app in SvelteKit and Tauri. I'd like to be able to give users the option to define themes through `.css` files (or whatever works). My app currently handles colours through a set of variables defined in `+layout.svelte` like this:

```css
:root {
        --w500: #f4f3f2;
        --bg400: #dbd6d0;
        --bg500: #F3EEE7;
        --bg600: #f4f0e9;
        --g100: #121212;
}
```

Is there any way I could do something similar (maintaining some kind of set of color variables for use in CSS) while loading styles dynamically from a file?

Comment: You can put your variables into some classes and the template switch adds one one of them to the body tag.

Comment: @kolja Would that not require that any additional colour scheme is put into the project source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add `<link>` or `<style>` elements using either [`<svelte:head>`](https://svelte.dev/docs/special-elements#svelte-head) or [`onMount`](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte#onmount). If you use `onMount` the element should be removed again in the cleanup function.

Just using a `<style>` and setting its contents is probably easier, then you do not have to worry about serving dynamic files.

I have found that `<svelte:head>` can lead to inconsistent results as elements can be added earlier or later depending on whether a route adding the elements was server or client-rendered. (For CSS, later styles overwrite rules with identical selectors.)

Comment: I'll definitely give this a try, and if it does I'll leave a comment with code details specifying my exact use case. Now that you've said it this is the blindingly obvious solution. I was really mainly struggling with remembering how one could even load a dynamic CSS file.

Comment: This worked perfectly for my use case. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped, you can accept answers using the checkmark outline to the left.